# SSH tunnel from local machine to remote server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel

I have SSH access to `aus-ssh`. I want to connect from `indo-client` to `aus-ssh` on port 9090, knowing that all traffic will be sent to `aus-remote` in port 80 (and then the same thing again for port 443).

**NOTE: I am already logged in onto `aus-ssh` via ssh, and *must* run the command on the `aus-ssh` serveritself, rather than on `indo-client`.**

The internet is full of explanation on what SSH command I should run on `indo-client` to connect to `aus-ssh` so that it tunnels my requests to `aus-remote`. That's NOT what I am after. I am unable to SSH straight to `aus-ssh`.

How do I do that?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by your wording. In your first sentence you state "I have SSH access to `aus-ssh`, but in your last sentence you state you are unable to log in directly to `aus-ssh` by SSH. Do you mean you can log into `aus-ssh` from some other system, but not from `indo-client`?

Comment: That is correct. I have to hop onto a different server, and THEN ssh onto aus-ssh. That's because `aus-ssh` only accepts connections from a specific IP, and `indo-client`'s IP is _very_ changable

Comment: Use ProxyCommand.

Comment: @jakuje Use what? How? Please explain.